# ITN Callbacks from Payfast API

Tags: php, callback

How do I integrate the notify URL into the my code after using the generated HTML code from the payfast dashboard?

I have the Randomly generated button with a shipping form
and this is what i have in the form part of the code

BUTTON:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function click_8eb310a4f3ae8dcc6556286f70cbd30f( aform_reference ) {
        var aform = aform_reference;
        aform['amount'].value = Math.round( aform['amount'].value*Math.pow( 10,2 ) )/Math.pow( 10,2 );
                    aform['custom_quantity'].value = aform['custom_quantity'].value.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g,"" );
                    if( !aform['custom_quantity'].value || 0 === aform['custom_quantity'].value.length || /^\s*$/.test( aform['custom_quantity'].value ) ) {
                        alert ( 'A quantity is required' );
                        return false;
                    }
        for( i=0; i<aform.elements.length; i++ )
          if( aform.elements[i].className == 'shipping' )
            aform.elements[i].value = aform.elements[i].value.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g,"" );
        var cont = true;
        for( i=0; i<aform.elements.length; i++ ) {

            if( aform.elements[i].className != 'shipping' )
                continue;

            if( aform.elements[i].name == 'line2' )
                continue;

            if( ! cont )
                continue;

            if( aform.elements[i].name == 'country' ) {
                if( aform.elements[i].selectedIndex == 0 ) {
                    cont = false;
                    alert ( 'Select a country' );
                }
            }   else    {
                if( 0 === aform.elements[i].value.length || /^\s*$/.test( aform.elements[i].value ) ) {
                    cont = false;
                    alert ( 'Complete all the mandatory address fields' );
                }
            }
        }
        if( ! cont )
            return cont;aform['amount'].value *=  parseInt( aform['custom_quantity'].value );
        var shipping_info = '';
        for( i=0; i<aform.elements.length; i++ )
          if( aform.elements[i].className == 'shipping' )
            shipping_info+=' '+aform.elements[i].name+' ['+aform.elements[i].value+']';

        aform['item_description'].value+= ' Shipping Information '+shipping_info

}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" name="form_8eb310a4f3ae8dcc6556286f70cbd30f" onsubmit="return click_8eb310a4f3ae8dcc6556286f70cbd30f( this );" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_paynow">
<input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="12700124">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item_name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="return_url">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="cancel_url">
```

Comment: Adding your attempts would help

Comment: I Hope thats enough

Comment: please go through the official api.  https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#web-integration

Answer (score 0):

An ITN **is not sent** for the PayFast HTML generated buttons.

A button is different to a custom integration in that it uses the `cmd` and `receiver` hidden fields, instead of the `merchant_id` and `merchant_key` hidden fields (as per the developer [documentation](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#checkout-page)).

You will also need to add a `notify_url` so that PayFast knows where to send the ITN return variables, which can then be accessed via the global $_POST variable in your `notify_url` script.

You need change your form to be as follows in order to receive an ITN:

```
<form action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" name="form_8eb310a4f3ae8dcc6556286f70cbd30f" onsubmit="return click_8eb310a4f3ae8dcc6556286f70cbd30f( this );" method="post">
  <!-- new merchant identifier fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="10000102">
  <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="46f0cd694581a">
  <!-- Existing fields from the button -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item_name">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="return_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="cancel_url">
  <!-- new notify_url -->
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://yoursite.com/notify/">
</form>
```

**Optional change:**

Because you will now be receiving an ITN, there is no need to use the generated JavaScript to compile the shipping fields into a single string for use in the `item_description` hidden field. Instead, you can make use of the PayFast `custom_str` form fields to capture the user's address.

```
<input type="text" name="custom_str1" placeholder="Address line 1">
```